# Can OS (iOS, Android, macOS, Windows) Read type of data being uploaded by Applications (even if encrypted)

Tags: android, ios, types, upload, operating-system

Not a super technical person here (just T-SQL programmer). I'm writing a original novel for  and like to put as much realism as possible based on current real technology.

Can Operating systems whether personal computers or mobile devices able to read the type of data being uploaded by a third party application to the cloud or via bluetooth? If so how is it done the background behind it? what if the upload is encrypted (E2E)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OS can see the data while it’s just a variable in the app (way before it is encrypted and sent). If the app can see it, the OS can.

Also, you call OS functions to send things over the Internet, so it can see it then as well. And, you typically encrypt using OS functions as well.

But, even if you encrypt with your own code, at some point you need to decrypt and use the data, and the OS can see all of your memory.

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind going bit further into how one might be able to track the type of data being uploaded by an APP by the OS? Just for the details.

Comment: At the core is a socket send function that takes a buffer of bytes. The OS would need to concatenate these calls and analyze them. It’s usually not hard to reverse engineer what public protocol is being used by analyzing the bytes.

Comment: It’s hard to imagine being able to successfully defend against a malicious OS